# Modifying SwaggerUI to remove required PathParam

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have a requirement to use optional path parameters. So made it like below;

```
@ApiOperation(httpMethod = "GET", value = "Get User Details With Optional Path Parameters", notes = "Output depends on values provided")
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "We do not unserstand what you mean"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "You are not requesting like a BOSS.") })
@RequestMapping(value = { "/getuser/userid/{userid}",
        "/getuser",
        "/getuser/userid/{userid}/alias/{alias}", "getuser/alias/{alias}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
private UserSchema getUserDetails(
        @PathVariable Optional<String> userid,
        @PathVariable Optional<String> alias) {
    Users user = null;
    UserSchema returningSchema = buildDefaultSchema();
    if (alias.isPresent()) {
        //Get The Value
    } else {
        //Try Get Other Value and do stuff etc.
    }
    //Similar for userid

    try {
        //Get User Data From DB
        user = dao.getUserData(userid,alias);
        //Bind data to returning schema
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.error(getClass().getName(), ex);
        returningSchema.setResponseText("Something is Wrong");
    } 
    return returningSchema;
}
```

But with swagger, its not allowing to make a request, as `PathVariables` are `required` type. I do not know much javascript. Tried [this](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/380) solution to modify the `swagger-ui.js`, but seem to get lost in the huge file and cannot find the portion mentioned.

I use the latest Swagger-UI version. Is it possible i can make the request with optional path variables and the correct path should be shown in swagger?

**NOTE**: I know swagger spec does not allow optional path variables. But i want to change this in my app only.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can definitely fork swagger-js and swagger-ui to support this.  Take a look at the `Operation.prototype.getMissingParams` in `operation.js`.